# Read variable in curl request (shell)

Tags: shell, variables, unix, curl, command

I'm trying to send a push notification whenever there is an nginx error on my server using push bullet, the curl request works and I receive the notification but when i try to insert a variable into the '--data-binary' option the script breaks.

```
push() {
 while read str; do
  #echo "$str";
  curl --header 'Access-Token: XXX' \
  -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary "{'type': 'note', 'title': 'nginx', 'body': "$str"}"
 done;
}

tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log | push
```

I've played around with the quotation marks but can seem to get it to work. Does anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have one string and the double quotes of the JSON data should be escaped:

```
--data-binary "{\"type\": \"note\", \"title\": \"nginx\", \"body\": \"$str\"}"
```

Comment: if i use the above it returns an error. i think the JSON has to be in this format with single quotes on the outside and double on the inside:

    --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "nginx", "body": "$str"}'

however this sends "$str" rather than the variable's value. Is it true that variables referenced inside quotes will never be evaluated?

Comment: glad to see that works for you :), do not hesitate to upvote and accept the answer if that solves your problem

Comment: I’ve accepted the answer but I don’t have enough rep to upvote sorry